# Transformations and inflection points

Tags: regression

I have some data that plots essentially like an exponential of something of the form y=100+x^0.000001, i.e., almost two asymptotes on x and y with a small bend at the origin in Q1 (i.e., L-shaped with a curve connecting the two lines that is < 5% of the line.) I would like to be able to estimate the inflection point (where the tangent slope = -1) of this plot. As expected, a great estimate of the relation is y=a + b*ln(x). Of course, even with some calculus, b is not the inflection point of y on x since now it is y on ln(x). Is there any way to get this from the b*ln(x) estimate or some other way to estimate this point (that is, the inflection point of the graph of y on x)??

Comment: FWIW, this is not what "inflection point" usually means.  Regardless, if you have a means to estimate $b,$ then nothing prevents you from finding an $(x,y)$ pair where $dy/dx=-1:$ it's simple algebra.  It's confusing, though, that $y=a+b\log x$ is a very different model than $y=\alpha+x^\beta:$ which one do you want to fit?  They will give different answers.